# Serializing Data Without Placeholder Key Names in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, highcharts

I am trying to modify the default WebAPI controller in VS2013 to return data in a way that can be consumed by HighCharts (in this case a Javascript timestamp and a value), and I've gotten pretty close with this code:

```
// GET: api/Readings
    public HttpResponseMessage GetReadings(DateTime? starttime = null, DateTime? endtime = null, string name = "", string deviceId = "", bool latest = false, bool highcharts = false)
    {
        if (starttime == null)
        {
            starttime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1);
        }
        if (endtime == null)
        {
            endtime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }

        var readings = from r in db.Readings
                       join d in db.Devices on r.DeviceID equals d.Id
                       where (r.Timestamp >= starttime && r.Timestamp <= endtime)
                       select r;

        if (name != "")
        {
            readings = readings.Where(p => p.Name == name);
        }

        if (deviceId != "")
        {
            readings = readings.Where(p => p.DeviceID == deviceId);
        }

        if (latest)
        {
            readings = readings.OrderByDescending(r => r.Timestamp).Take(1);
        }
        else
        {
            readings = readings.OrderBy(r => r.Timestamp);
        }

        if (highcharts)
        {
            var values = new List<Tuple<long, double>> { };

            var data = readings.ToArray();
            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                values.Add(new Tuple<long, double>(item.Timestamp.ToJavascriptTimestamp(), item.Value) );
            }
            return ControllerContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, values);
        }
        return ControllerContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, readings);
    }
```

The challenge I am facing is that the output produced, which I want to look like this (sample from http://www.highcharts.com/studies/live-server-data.php, used in http://www.highcharts.com/studies/live-server.htm and from the tutorial http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data):

```
[1433364572000, 3]
```

Instead looks like this:

```
[{"m_Item1":1433364610337,"m_Item2":65.5}]
```

It appears that when the list of tuples gets serialized, it adds the generic m_Item1 and m_item2 keys.

I need to know what to do with my data in the `if (highcharts)` block to get it to output in the required highcharts friendly format.

Comment: This is an array with 2 values:

    [1433364572000, 3]

This is an array of objects with property names: (In this case it has a single value)

    [{"m_Item1":1433364610337,"m_Item2":65.5}]    I'd suggest either ditching the tuples and outputting an array, or just concatenating the numbers together manually in the correct format.

Comment: Instead of serialize you can also modify names: m_Item1 should be x and m_Item2 should be y. Maybe it will be simpler to implement.